# grid colspan does not work for IE in GWT

Tags: gwt

I was created the grid in GWT
and set the attribute colspan for one row...

```
gridSample.setWidget(0, 0, new HTML("Can you improve this checklist?  Please rank and submit your comments below"));

gridSample.getCellFormatter().getElement(0, 0).setAttribute("colspan", "4");
```

The colspan does not work for IE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your using the `Grid` class. This class is not intended to be used with flexible column and rows, thus setting colspan is not supported. If you want to set colspan, use the class `FlexTable`. It does support colspan. In your case when using `FlexTable` it looks:

```
gridSanple.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(0, 0, 4);
```

However, note that `FlexTable` is much slower then `Grid`. So if you have a large table this might be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

In IE has bug. When I use:

```
flexTable.getCellFormatter().getElement(hNum, 0).setAttribute("colspan", ""+colCount);
```

GWT writes attribute name as "colSpan" with upper case S, for IE (if open developer tools, in IE, I can see it) but IE8 ignored it, when I modify to "colspan" it correctly works.
But I don't know, how to fix it in GWT... GWT writes it self...
But it really works

```
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setColSpan(hNum, 0, colCount);
```

Comment: Yep, that's it, there is a bug, either in IE (also the case in IE 11) or in GWT. `getElement(...).setAttribute("colspan", ...)` worked for me, tested with GWT 2.6

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gridSample.getCellFormatter().getElement(0, 0).setAttribute("colSpan", "4")
```

I mean use `colSpan` instead `colspan`.